With the help of the duality theorem, show that the calculations have an error.
Consider the next model
$$
\begin{array}{rr}
\max & z=-2 x_1+x_2 \\
\text { s. t } & 3 x_1+2 x_2 \leq 6 \\
& 6 x_1+3 x_2 \leq 10 \\
& x_1, x_2 \geq 0
\end{array}
$$
Suppose that the optimal table for the row corresponding to $\operatorname{the} z_j-c_j$ is




$x_1$
$x_2$
$h_1$
$h_2$
sol




$z_j-c_j$
0
2
0
1
$\frac{20}{3}$



With the help of the duality theorem, show that the calculations have an error.
I think its because (0,1) is the optimal solution to dual problem and $w=6y_1+10y_2$ then $w(0,1)=10 \neq 20/3$ but I don't know im stuck

Given the primal problem
$$
\begin{array}{rr}
\max & z=-2 x_1+x_2 \\
\text { s. t } & 3 x_1+2 x_2 \leq 6 \\
& 6 x_1+3 x_2 \leq 10 \\
& x_1, x_2 \geq 0
\end{array}
$$
The corresponding dual is
$$
\begin{array}{rr}
\min & w=6y_1+10y_2 \\
\text { s. t } & 3y_1+6y_2\ge-2 \\
& 2y_1+3y_2\ge 1 \\
& y_1, y_2 \geq 0
\end{array}
$$
By the graphical method, the solution to the dual is $(y^*_1,y^*_2)=(\frac{1}{2},0)$ where $w=3$.

Strong duality suggests that $z^*=w^*$, therefore $z^*$ should equal three (which can also be seen graphically). Let's assume, however, that we can't use the graphical method for the primal. Then we must use this important fact (sourced from page 7 here):

Assume problem (P) has a solution $x^*$ and problem (D) has a solution
$y^*$.

If $x^*_j > 0$, then the $j^{th}$ constraint in (D) is binding.
If the $j^{th}$ constraint in (D) is not binding, then $x_j^*=0$.
If $y_i^* > 0$, then the $i^{th}$ constraint in (P) is binding.
If the $i^{th}$ constraint in (P) is not binding, then $y_i^* = 0$.


Therefore constraint $6x_1 + 2x_2\le6$ should be binding in the primal since $y_1>0$. Additionally, note that the constraint $3y_1+6y_2\ge-2$ is not binding in the dual, then that suggests $x^*_1=0$. Therefore,
$$6x_1^* + 2x_2^*=6$$
$$2x_2^*=6$$
$$x_2^*=3$$
Thus the given solution of the primal, $\frac{20}{3}$, is incorrect not only because it doesn't meet strong duality, in that $\frac{20}{3}\neq3$, but we can also show the real solution to the primal is $(x_1^*,x_2^*)=(0,3)$ which leads to $z^*=3$ with the notion of complementary slackness.
